# Services in Multiagent Systems

Tags: multi-agent

in MultiAgents Systems:

1. Every agent provides just one service?or is possible more than one?
2. Every agent consumes just one service?or is possible to consume more than one?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a general question:

1. Could be more than one. Theoretically there could be one agent providing all the services
2. Could be more than one. Theoretically there could be one agent consuming all the services

If you are talking about a specific multi-agent architecture/design/programming language please specify your question!